# Ruby Savon 2 gem: cannot specify XML child and sub-child elements to make valid request to SOAP API Webservice

Tags: ruby, xml, soap, soapui, savon

Have done a huge amount of googling and looked at the Savon 2 documentation but I don't think I am correctly specifying in my ruby code the XML child and sub-child elements I need to run a successful request to this SOAP webservice.

In main2.rb I have tried to use square bracket syntax to go down the document from BookReservationRequest to Booker to UserWithoutALogin. (This square bracket approach worked in another example on the response side). Somehow I am not specifying these properly in Ruby as when I delete these tags in SOAP UI, I get exactly the same error message below. (N.B I am still quite new to Ruby!)

Full error trace:

```
ruby main2.rb
/Users/dan14/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/response.rb:85:in `raise_soap_and_http_errors!': (soap:Server) System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (Savon::SOAPFault)
   at Services.Internal.Helpers.CustomerHelper.GetCustomerIdFromGuestOrBookerType(Nullable`1 partnerServiceId, GuestOrBookerType guestOrBookerType) in c:\TeamCity\LB-QA-04\work\e2ec20c745b940f9\Source\Services\Internal\Helpers\CustomerHelper.cs:line 64
   at Services.Internal.Service.BookReservation(BookReservationRequest bookReservationRequest) in c:\TeamCity\LB-QA-04\work\e2ec20c745b940f9\Source\Services\Internal\Service.asmx.cs:line 289
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    from /Users/dan14/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/response.rb:14:in `initialize'
    from /Users/dan14/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/operation.rb:72:in `new'
    from /Users/dan14/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/operation.rb:72:in `create_response'
    from /Users/dan14/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/operation.rb:58:in `call'
    from /Users/dan14/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/client.rb:36:in `call'
    from main2.rb:11:in `core_info'
    from main2.rb:23:in `<main>'
```

Ruby code (main2.rb):

```
require 'savon'

class BookReservation

  def client
    client = Savon.client(wsdl: "http://some-example-soap-wsdl-link", follow_redirects: :follow_redirects)
  end

  def core_info(partner_code, restaurant_location_id, session_id, dining_date_and_time, size)
    message = { 'PartnerCode' => partner_code, 'RestaurantLocationId' => restaurant_location_id, 'SessionId' => session_id, 'DiningDateAndTime' => dining_date_and_time, 'Size' => size }
    response = client.call(:book_reservation, message: message)
    response.hash[:book_reservation_response]
  end

  def booker_info(first_name, last_name, email, guest_accepts_email_marketing)
    message = { 'FirstName' => first_name, 'LastName' => last_name, 'EMail' => email, 'GuestAcceptsEmailMarketingFromPartner' => guest_accepts_email_marketing }
    response = client.call([:book_reservation][:booker][:user_without_a_login], message: message)
    response.body[:book_reservation_response]
  end
end

  book = BookReservation.new
  puts book.core_info("DEV-DAN-BETH:73411", "10799", "DINNER", "2015-06-20T21:00:00", "2", )
  puts book.booker_info("John", "Smith", "john.smith@example.com", "true")
```

This xml document in SoapUI returns a valid / successful response everytime:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://schemas.livebookings.net/OneFormat/Aggregator/Internal/1/0/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>      
        <ns:BookReservationRequest>            
            <ns:PartnerCode>DEV-DAN-BETH:73411</ns:PartnerCode>
            <ns:RestaurantLocationId>10799</ns:RestaurantLocationId>
            <ns:SessionId>DINNER</ns:SessionId>
            <ns:DiningDateAndTime>2015-06-20T21:00:00</ns:DiningDateAndTime>
            <ns:Size>2</ns:Size>
            <ns:Booker>
                <ns:UserWithoutALogin>
                    <ns:FirstName>John</ns:FirstName>
                    <ns:LastName>Smith</ns:LastName>
                    <ns:EMail>john.smith@example.com</ns:EMail>                      
                    <ns:GuestAcceptsEmailMarketingFromPartner>true</ns:GuestAcceptsEmailMarketingFromPartner>
               </ns:UserWithoutALogin>
            </ns:Booker>       
        </ns:BookReservationRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Example of successful response in SoapUI:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <BookReservationResponse xmlns="http://schemas.livebookings.net/OneFormat/Aggregator/Internal/1/0/">
         <ConfirmationNumber>T2NVGBUN</ConfirmationNumber>
         <ReservationId>34277666</ReservationId>
         <AllowedToCancelOnline>true</AllowedToCancelOnline>
      </BookReservationResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Also I've tried converting the booker and user_without_a_login symbols in square brackets to the original xml camel case strings - ie: ['Booker']['UserWithoutALogin'] but this also doesn't work - get exactly same error message!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SOAP message example contains a Body that contains a Book Reservation Request that includes a Booker block.

your `BookReservation` class, however, contains two methods that call the Savon client - one of these sends a `BookReservationRequest` - but you never add the Booker to the message hash before dispatching it.

It's almost 100% certain that your client is sending an invalid SOAP request because you have not specified the `<ns:Booker>` block in your SOAP body.

I suspect that if you updated your class to contain one method that looked as follows:

```
def execute(partner_code, restaurant_location_id, session_id, dining_date_and_time, size, first_name, last_name, email, guest_accepts_email_marketing)
    message = { 'PartnerCode' => partner_code, 'RestaurantLocationId' => restaurant_location_id, 'SessionId' => session_id, 'DiningDateAndTime' => dining_date_and_time, 'Size' => size }
    message.merge!('Booker' => { 'FirstName' => first_name, 'LastName' => last_name, 'EMail' => email, 'GuestAcceptsEmailMarketingFromPartner' => guest_accepts_email_marketing })

    response = client.call(:book_reservation, message: message)
    response.hash[:book_reservation_response]
```

end

And called it with:

```
book.execute(
  "DEV-DAN-BETH:73411", "10799", "DINNER", "2015-06-20T21:00:00", "2",
   "John", "Smith", "john.smith@example.com", "true" )
```

You'd have better luck.

Comment: Thanks @macfinnigan feel like we are almost there, I just tried your solution but now I'm getting a new error: `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Savon::SOAPFault)` surely I need to also specify 'UserWithoutALogin' within Booker - how do I do this in the code?

Comment: Also do all the values in the execute call need to be strings? ie. also the "2" and "true"?

Comment: I edited it to this: `message.merge!('Booker' => {'UserWithoutALogin' => { 'FirstName' => first_name, 'LastName' => last_name, 'EMail' => email, 'GuestAcceptsEmailMarketingFromPartner' => guest_accepts_email_marketing }})` and when run got no error but no data printed.

Comment: Not to worry, made a few minor edits and get the response data to print. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear you got there.  I always use the approach of dumping generated XML to log or to console, so that I can see why it's different to what it should be.  XML is a pain in the ass.  :)

Comment: you really helped me before, but now I've got another similar problem - but this time accessing a heavily nested hash (parsed from xml) - I need to access all the values and set them as instance variables - any ideas? This is the raw data I'm working with: https://gist.github.com/daneasterman/4dafacbd6d5a5e3dbcb1